# Void-variable error when lambda function calls itself

Tags: lexical-scoping

Here's a simple test:

```
(let ((func (lambda (i)
              (when (> i 0)
                (print i)
                (funcall func (1- i))))))
  (funcall func 3))
```

It says `(void-variable func)`, but why? When `(funcall func 3)` is called then func already has a value. Why doesn't the inside of the lambda see the dynamically bound variable?

Comment: My crystal ball says this is a duplicate question. Hope someone has the time to track down the duplicate and close, if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the inside of the lambda see the dynamically bound variable?

Because it isn't actually dynamically bound.

Check the value of `lexical-binding` in the buffer where this form is located. While it is `t` evaluating this form raises this error. Once you have set it to `nil` it will work.

It would be better to stick to lexical bindings instead of doing that by letting the the `lambda` capture the lexically bound `func` like so:

```
(let (func)
  (setq func (lambda (i)
               (when (> i 0)
                 (print i)
                 (funcall func (1- i))))))
  (funcall func 3))
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, lexical-binding was on.Tricky.

Comment: The `letrec` form should allow for this case directly.

Comment: In fact, `letrec` is a macro and expands to the code in the answer.